# Magento 2 City field not required on checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, validation

How to make **city** field not required on checkout, i'm using luma theme?

Comment: Provide your work with your your query

Comment: You should do the similar things like in the described answer http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/163152/magento-2-1-update-shipping-rate-on-providing-zipcode-in-cart-page/163207#163207, but in your case, it should be `city` instead `postcode`