# Update shipping rates on changing postcode on checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.2, shipping-methods

I'm trying to create a module with custom shipping method. So I've followed [this tutorial](http://inchoo.net/magento-2/creating-a-shipping-method-in-magento-2/) to create it. [This link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/163152/magento-2-1-update-shipping-rate-on-providing-zipcode-in-cart-page/163207) and [this link](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_carrier.html), to configure shipping carrier validations.

The problem is, if I change the zip/postcode, the shipping's value does not change. My question is, how can I update the shipping cost value when customer update its address information (postcode to be more specific)? Or when we use the guest-checkout and there is no address information?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. The problem is on your xml definition of the rates validation:

```
<item name="shipping-rates-validation" xsi:type="array">
      <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="inchoo" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Inchoo_Shipping/js/view/inchoo</item>
            </item>
      </item>
</item>
```

In your xml, when you define the js validator:

`<item name="inchoo" xsi:type="array">`

You must change the name to:

`<item name="inchoo-rates-validation" xsi:type="array">`

And **inchoo** must be **the same** as carrier code of your shipping method. The problem is when magento try lo find and load all validators in :

...vendor/magento/module-checkout/Block/Checkout/LayoutProcessor.php

on method **processShippingChildrenComponents**

```
private function processShippingChildrenComponents($shippingRatesLayout)
{
    $activeCarriers = $this->getShippingConfig()->getActiveCarriers(
        $this->getStoreResolver()->getCurrentStoreId()
    );
    foreach (array_keys($shippingRatesLayout) as $carrierName) {
        $carrierKey = str_replace('-rates-validation', '', $carrierName);
        if (!array_key_exists($carrierKey, $activeCarriers)) {
            unset($shippingRatesLayout[$carrierName]);
        }
    }
    return $shippingRatesLayout;
}
```

If magento does not find the same name as carrier, unset the file in layout.

Regards

Mauro M. Martinez

Comment: Thanks for answering, but it does not work here yet, I can't see what is wrong, can you please check my code [here](https://github.com/luizpaulofranz/Magento2-ShippingMethod)?

Comment: In your confi.xml, your carrier code is bad:
 https://github.com/luizpaulofranz/Magento2-ShippingMethod/blob/master/etc/config.xml

You defined the code as "example" and in :

https://github.com/luizpaulofranz/Magento2-ShippingMethod/blob/master/Model/Carrier/Example.php

the code is:

protected $_code = 'inchoo';

Comment: Maxiliano Martinez Thankyou so much, now I get it, and it works perfectly!

Comment: What about magento 1.9.x “Please specify a shipping method” error https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/225297/57334

Answer (score 0):

Please find below the solution

```
 <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
 <body>
     <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
             <arguments>
                 <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                     <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                         <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                             <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                 <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                     <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                         <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                             <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                 <!-- add a new validator-->
                                                 <item name="step-config" xsi:type="array">
                                                     <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                         <item name="shipping-rates-validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                             <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                 <item name="asap-rates-validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                     <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Company_Modulename/js/view/asap</item>
                                                                 </item>
                                                             </item>
                                                         </item>
                                                     </item>
                                                 </item>
                                             </item>
                                         </item>
                                     </item>
                                 </item>
                             </item>
                         </item>
                     </item>
                 </argument>
             </arguments>
     </referenceBlock>
 </body>
```

Please note that you should use the carrier name for 'asap'.

```
<item name="asap-rates-validation" xsi:type="array">
     <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Company_Modulename/js/view/asap</item>
</item>
```