# Please specify shipping method with custom shipping method - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, custom-shipping-method

I've been trying to add **custom shipping methods** to a **Magento 2 webshop,** using configurations in **`app/code/vendor/module/etc/config.xml`**, **`app/code/vendor/module/etc/system.xml`** and **`app/code/vendor/module/Model/Carrier/Shippingmethod.php`**.

So, this all works, and I can select the shipping methods. Also, when NOT logged in, the checkout works fine and can get completed.

The problem is, when logged in with a **`(new) customer`**, when using one of the custom shipping methods, it throws the following error:
`'Please specify a shipping method' (freely translated from original language).`
The console throws the following error:

[image: Error payment-information]

When I go the following link:

> http://mywebshop.com/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/payment-information

It says:
**`"User not authorized for %resources"`** and a  `<trace>` tag with a few **`php files`**:

[image]

Some research later, people talk about **`tokens and stuff`**, but can't figure it out.

Comment: Can look into this link: https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Please-specify-a-shipping-method-when-logged-in-user-try-to/m-p/104531#M6365

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this possibly occurs because new customers do not have an address registered, I've pass throug problems with custom shipping too, see [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/210868/update-shipping-rates-on-changing-postcode-on-checkout-page) question, maybe helps you.

And see [my example](https://github.com/luizpaulofranz/Magento2-ShippingMethod) of custom shipping method.

I hope it help

Comment: The new customers had an address specified beforehand, so that wouldn't have been the issue. I have used your example on Git, and after some modifications that works. I still want to know why mine did not work, cause it did not vary that much from yours, only that some values were obtained by setters and yours by a rand() or hardcoded.

Comment: your shipping method code, setted on app/code/vendor/module/Model/Carrier/Shippingmethod.php, must not contain "_" and can't be bigger than 40, like @Siarhey Uchukhlebau says. Check the system.xml and config.xml too, all carriers_code must be the same, send me your github, I'll take a look.

Comment: Due to the fact that this is for an internship, I cannot share my code with you unfortunately. But as @Siarhey Uchukhlebau, my method code did indeed include an '_' and was longer than 40 symbols! So that was the problem. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Will you pls help me  : “Please specify a shipping method” error @ https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/225297/57334

Answer (score 7):

Another reason of that issue could be long method code (>40 symbols) or multiple symbols `_` in the full method code (carrier code+method code). Check this data when it sending from the checkout to the backend.

Comment: What exactly are you meaning by 'long method code'? The Model/Carrier/Customshipping.php code itself is 76 lines long, so >40 symbols.

Comment: @bramulous Before the 2.2.0 release the `shipping_method` column in the table `quote_address` has length 40, so if your code >40 bytes it will be cropped by mysql (during insert/update). After the 2.2.0 Magento update it's length set to the 120 byte.

Comment: Okay okay, so maybe a stupid question: how do I know if my code is longer than '40 bytes'?

Comment: @bramulous Sum the `carrier_code`, the `method_code` and one symbol `_`

Comment: Ah like so! And the code indeed contained an '_' and the name was to too long. Thank you, all settled now!

Comment: anyone help me “Please specify a shipping method” error https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/225297/57334