# OnePage Checkout Page Error - Free Shipping error : “Please specify a shipping method”

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, shopping-cart-price-rules, debugging, alert

My condition, **free shipping for selected zip-code/postal code,**
range is, **from 600003 to 600151**

I am using Shopping Cart Price Rule, my workout

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Note : Shopping Cart Price Rule condition Matching still alert open

**I am using Multistore**

How can i solve this error.

Note: Log Error

```
2018-05-17T10:48:21+00:00 ERR (3): 
Mage_Core_Exception: Please specify a shipping method. in /home/abc/public_html/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /home/abc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(303): Mage::throwException('Please specify ...')
#1 /home/abc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(222): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->_validate()
#2 /home/abc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(238): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitNominalItems()
#3 /home/abc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php(812): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitAll()
#4 /home/abc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php(604): Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage->saveOrder()
#5 /home/abc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Checkout_OnepageController->saveOrderAction()
#6 /home/abc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('saveOrder')
#7 /home/abc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#8 /home/abc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#9 /home/abc/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#10 /home/abc/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#11 {main}
```

Comment: I took a look but I don't have an environment set up where I can give this a proper test. Can you try adjusting `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php` on line 302(ish) find: `if (!$this->getQuote()->isVirtual() && (!$method || !$rate)) {` and remove the `|| !$rate` bit?  If that works I will provide an answer that will help you set up a module that fixes your problem. After you've tested it, undo your change. This is just to test.

Comment: i just remove the line : Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Please specify a shipping method.'));  now customer place the order without selecting the shipping, and thanks for your knowledge sharing.

Comment: Is it working with default shipping options? If yes then try to use webshopapps matrixrate where you can manage the shipping title and price according to country, state, zipcodes, weight etc.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: @snh_nl Yes, see here https://snag.gy/Em8JZl.jpg  path -> app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php

Comment: You just removed the warning? But does the order then have a shipping method still?!!

Comment: For me its working,

Answer (score 0):

try to change the  free shipping option in your rule  to For shipment with matching items instead of For matching items only. 
Good luck !!!

Comment: Today i am getting same error, my error log : https://justpaste.it/62v1x

Comment: hey , plz try to verify all  conditions in your shopping cart price rule?

Comment: No conflict, other things looking good.

Comment: i don't know honestly why ur customer end with error

Comment: I am using multi store, the error :  #10 /home/abcd/public_html/index.php(88): Mage::run('', 'store').  what is mean this, and my  88th line is : /* Store or website code */
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';

/* Run store or run website */
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';

Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);

Comment: Its wokring... just remove the line...

Comment: @zus did not understand what u mean

Comment: see this -https://snag.gy/Em8JZl.jpg

Comment: what is the file that u change it and remove the line from it?

Comment: app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php

Comment: @zus you shouldn't modify magento core files