# Shopping Cart Price Rules - Category Discount Issue

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount, category-products, offers

Workout:

[image]

[image]

Output:

[image]

Condition :

Selected Category Product Discount -> 10%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems to be working as expected (If category exists in basket apply discount to all items)

You need to specify the category in the actions I think to do what you want.

Comment: Like same will you pls help me here -> https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/225297/57334